# How to share file using bluetooth in react-native

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, sharing

I have a requirement in my new project to share files using Bluetooth.
I have searched many share plugins for react native but unable to get a Bluetooth option. So far I am using `react-native-share` and I am able to achieve share via e-mail and WhatsApp but now I need Bluetooth also.

```
 shareWhatsapp(way){
   const shareOptions = {
      title: 'Share via',
      message: 'some message',
      url: self.state.path_share,
      type:'pdf',
      subject:'Sma Report',
      social:way,
      showAppsToView:true
  };
 Share.shareSingle(shareOptions);
}
```

in way parameter I am passing 
   for WhatsApp  `Share.Social.WHATSAPP` and `Share.Social.EMAIL` for email.

Comment: explore this library for working with Bluetooth in React native https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ble-manager

Comment: @TalhaSiddiqi thanks man but it didn't help.

Comment: I can't believe it's been 3.5 years and I gave the first thumbs Up and there literally zero answers still! 

I also can’t believe that there’s no React Native app out there that never needed Bluetooth file sharing, especially now, with the latest Android's incredibly strict permissions?

Comment: @GianhTran why didn't this work? Have you tried recently? It looks nice and its also quite active https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager/graphs/contributors